# Is it possible to regard -id as a suffix forming adjectives in Modern English?

Tags: morphology

The morphemic status of -id can be proved by its regular occurrence in [Modern English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_English_language#Modern_English) adjectives (mostly of Roman origin): horrid, stupid, rapid, acid, sordid, valid, solid, etc.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @subic: what does "NE" mean in this context?

Comment: what does "NE" mean in *any* context?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [Wiktionary lists four](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NE#Abbreviation), including Nebraska and northeast.

Comment: @subic: I am sorry for the ignorance, but what is New English? Everything that is not Old English (Middle English, Early Modern English and Modern English)? Or contemporary English? From *[Old English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English)*: "The Old English period is followed by Middle English (12th to 15th century), Early Modern English (ca. 1480 to 1650) and finally Modern English (after 1650)."

Comment: New English stands for Modern English. We use abbreviation NE (New English) instead of ME (Modern English), because if we use abbreviations ME (Modern English) and ME (Middle English), they  can be confused [See http://books.google.com/books?id=aDZKAAAAYAAJ&q=OE+ME+NE&dq=OE+ME+NE&hl=ru&ei=pOsCTomaAovzsgbTjOmIDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CC4Q6AEwATgK}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest that it only makes sense to call something a "suffix" if either it is productive (i.e. you can use it to create new words from existing ones), or if the words in which it exists are envisaged by native speakers of being made of a smaller element plus that suffix.

In the case of -id, it's not clear to me that either of these are the case. If you can think of cases where you could create a plausible new word by adding -id to an existing one, or if you really think that speakers envisage, say, "stupid" as being made of the morpheme "stup(or)" plus -id, then you might want to call it a suffix. I personally don't think that either of these conditions are true.

[In Latin, "stupor" could mean what in English would now be "stupidity"-- i.e. to a Latin speaker, there was arguably a sense that "stupidus" was derived from a "suffix" -idus, but I don't think that today English speakers see "stupid" as being derived from "stupor" even though both words have been borrowed; and "solidus" possibly derived from e.g. "solum" (="base", "floor"), or at least they share a common derivation, but this notion is lost in English today, as indeed the relationship between Spanish "sólido"~"suelo" or French "solide"~"sol" has probably also been lost.]

Comment: That's the point. But what sources can I use to justify this approach (there must be some reference books even down loadable from some free e-book sites).I would be very grateful to you for this information.

Comment: Absolutely. By any useful definition of the term, **-id** isn't a 'suffix'.

Answer (score 6):

The NOAD describes *-id* as suffix used to form adjectives (such as *putrid* and *torrid*) or form nouns (such as *chrysalid* and *pyramid*).
In the first case, its origin is from Latin *-idus*; in the latter case, its origin is from Latin *-idis*, which derives from the Greek *-is*, *-id-*.
[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-id) describes the suffix with "appended to various foreign words to make an English adjective form" and "often added to words of Greek, sometimes Latin, origin."

The words you reported derives from Latin words that end in *idus* (*horridus*, *stupidus*, *rapidus*, *acidus*, *sordidus*, *validus*, *solidus*), but I would not see *valid* as *val* + *id*.

Comment: Thank you, what about -ics for forming nouns denoting different disciplines (phonetics, linguistics, politics, mathematics etc.)?

Comment: @subic That suffix derives from the French _-iques_, which then derives from the Latin _-ica_, or Greek _-ika_.

Comment: @subic: search this very site, and you will find:  [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/what-is-the-difference-between-a-singular-noun-and-a-plural-noun-treated-as-si/4657#4657), [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretic-al/6600#6600).