# Can you have a singular "dreg"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is it linguistically incorrect to singularise the word "dregs", as in the following example:

> He finished off every last dreg of his
>   coffee.

If so, are there any other English words which can only exist in plural form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

However rare, *[dreg](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dreg)* is indeed the singular form of *dregs*. The word enjoyed employment by Shakespeare in *Troilus and Cressida* (Act 3, Sc. 2):

> What too curious dreg espies my sweet lady in the fountain of our love?

I managed to gather a few words ending in *-s* that are most often used as plural-only: scissors, shears, tongs, trousers, measles, series, gallows, species, thanks, clothes, bellows, outskirts, pampas, premises, pajamas, rabies.

Comment: What do you call one half of a pair of scissors while you are making them ?

Comment: A tine? Or maybe a leg? :-)

Comment: @mgb That would be a _scissor_, also commonly used in _scissor kick_. _Scissor_ can also be used as a verb to describe the action of scissors.

Comment: Some of the words in your list I think are actually just singular words that happen to end in "s": Measles *is* dangerous (not *are*); similarly for *rabies*; This is *a* new species. (Some more of them can be singular or plural: Where *is/are* the gallows?; Pampas *is/are* a type of grass. Similarly you could add: Their headquarters *is/are* in London.)

Comment: @psmears Not an insignificant distinction, thanks.

Comment: "Specie" is often used in technical discussions of numismatics.

Comment: @psmears - here are 1000 more as posted in my answer: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_pluralia_tantum

Comment: @The Raven: Despite appearances, *specie* is not the singular of *species*. They are related - both come from the same Latin word (in different cases, hence the different endings) - but both are singular in Latin, and they have remained so in English.

Comment: You really need to distinguish between words whose singular happens to end with an "s", and words that are only or primarily used as plurals. We say "a pair of scissors" and a "pair of trousers", so I guess those are plurals. "Species" is spelled the same whether singular or plural: "one species, two species". (Not unique in that. Consider "fish", "sheep", etc)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not linguistically incorrect to use the word dreg: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dreg

There are many other *pluralia tantum* as mentioned in [this (closed) question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17403/are-there-nouns-that-are-always-plural-have-no-plural-counterpart) where I learned about 1000 [English pluralia tantum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_pluralia_tantum) and [Mass nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding this answer. The last sentence in particular: What comment are you referring to?

Comment: @MrHen See update. I was just irritated when I wasted time commenting instead of answering

Comment: Ah okay. No worries. :)