# What's the reason behind using "innings" more frequently than "inning"?

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the singular “innings” come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19/where-did-the-singular-innings-come-from)

Is there any difference between *inning* and *innings*? I think both can be used interchangeably.

But I haven't seen *inning* frequently used by any news channel or English newspaper. Is there any particular reason behind using *innings* more frequently than *inning*?

Comment: Americans [tend to use the singular](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inning%2Cinnings&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), but Brits [always use the plural](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inning%2Cinnings&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=). The (relatively few) counter-examples in that second link are probably mostly caused by mis-classification in Google Books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word in cricket is *innings* (which is singular). I believe the corresponding word in baseball is *inning*.

Comment: @Collin Fole It means both words can't be used interchangeably?

Comment: If you use the wrong one for the context, people will understand, but know you are unfamiliar with the game in question.

Comment: Baseball requires the distinction because every game has many *innings*, each of which is an *inning* - the first inning, second inning, &c. My understanding is that in a cricket match each team has only one *innings*, so there's ordinarily no need to distinguish singular and plural.

Comment: @Stoney  If we are referring to a test match in cricket then it has two innings viz. first and second innings. Can we use inning there according to your first statement?

Comment: @sudhir  Probably not; the dictionaries say that in cricket *innings* is both singular and plural; but I follow baseball (Go Cards!), not cricket, so look to someone more knowledgeable for a definitive answer.

Comment: A recognised cricketing authority uses his own plural, _inningses_, to make it clear when he's invoking the plural sense. Even though he only claims authority in his own field of expertise, I wouldn't argue with him - and I think he's actually found a sensible way of dealing with this corridor of uncertainty.

Comment: Observe also that in baseball, both teams appear during an *inning*, the visiting team in the *top half* and the home team in the *bottom half*. "Going into the bottom of the fourth inning, David Freese leading off for the Cardinals." A pitcher, however, is credited with *an inning pitched* for pitching a *half-inning*. If he comes out of the half-inning before it's completed, he's credited with a third of an inning pitched for each out recorded in that half-inning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- His name wouldn't be Gollum would it?

Comment: @StoneyB, wow - and yet this is a nation that claims to find cricket too complicated?

Comment: @mgb I don't find cricket complicated; I just don't have any opportunity to watch it and learn the finer points.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer with regards to American baseball (or softball), as I have no frame of reference for cricket.   In baseball, *inning* is singular and *innings* is plural.  So you can use both, but not interchangeably.

> We will go get popcorn during the fifth inning.
>
> They sing music during the seventh inning stretch.
>
> He pitched for three innings.
>
> Baseball normally lasts for nine innings.